# How to find a unique string within html and wrap it with a tag, but exclude links and urls

Tags: javascript, c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm looking for a way to look for a specific string within a page in the visible text and then wrap that string in `<em>` tags. I have tried used HTML Agility Pack and had some success with a `Regex.Replace` but if the string is included within a url it also gets replaced which I do not want, if it's within an image name, it gets replaced and this obviously breaks the link or image url.

An example attempt:

```
var markup = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
var replaced = Regex.Replace(markup, "product-xs", " <em>product</em>-xs", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        
var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(replaced);
    
    _stream.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
```

This does not work as it would replace a `<a href="product/product-xs">` with `<a href="product/<em>product</em>-xs">` - which I don't want.

The string is coming from a text string value within a CMS so the user can't wrap the words there and ideally, I want to catch all instances of the word that are already published.

Ideally I would want to exclude `<title>` tags, `<img>` tags and `<a>` tags, everything else should get the wrapped tag.

Before I used the HTML Agility Pack, a fellow front end dev tried it with JavaScript but that had an unexpected impact on dropdown menus.

If you need any more info, just ask.

Comment: Your question as stated is confusing "This would replace a <a href="product/product-xs"> with <a href="product/<em>product</em>-xe">" yet two sentences down you say you want to exclude `<a>` Please update your question to enhance the clarity of your objective

Comment: This is me doing my part to warn about parsing HTML with regular expressions. HTML is *not* a regular language. I'd consider using a library for this. Something like `HTML::Sanitizer`. Further reading https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - I'm showing what the current code does and that I want to exclude `<a>` tags from getting updates, which the current code doesn't do.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you don't really want to find all instances of "product-xs", you want to find all instances of "product-xs" inside of text nodes. i.e. <sometag>replace text in here</sometag> <sometag an-attribute="dont replace text in here"></sometag>.

Comment: @JasonElkin Correct. Basically any instance of the specific word that is visible to the user as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Agility Pack to select only the text nodes (i.e. the text that exists between any two tags) with a bit of XPath and modify them like this.

Looking only in body will exclude `<title>`, `<meta>` etc. The `not` excludes script tags, you can exclude others in the same way (or check the parent node in the loop).

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//*[not(self::script)]/text()"))
{
    var newNode = htmlDoc.CreateTextNode(node.InnerText.Replace("product-xs", "<em>product</em>-xs"));
    node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, node);
}
```

I've used a simple replace, regex will work fine too, prob best to check the performance of each approach and choose which works best for your use case.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Jason - I'll test it over the next couple of days. (sooner if I get a chance!)